# Core Graphics and Open GL Drawing

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiimageview, core-graphics

I have a drawing app where I'm using the openGL paint code to draw the strokes, but want to transfer it to another image after the stroke is complete, then clear the OpenGL view. and for that, I'm using CoreGraphics. I'm running into a problem however, where the OpenGL view is being cleared before the image is being transferred via CG (even though I clear it afterwards)

(And I want it the other way, ie the image to be drawn first then the painting image to be erased, to avoid any kind of flickering)

(paintingView is the openGL view)

Here is the code:

```
// Save the previous line drawn to the "main image"

UIImage *paintingViewImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
paintingViewImage = [_paintingView snapshot];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);
[self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mainImage.frame.size.width, self.mainImage.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

// Get the image from the painting view

[paintingViewImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mainImage.frame.size.width, self.mainImage.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self.paintingView erase];
```

So the paintingView is being erased before the mainImage.image variable is being set to the CurrentImage Context.

I'm a only a beginner with these, so any thoughts helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off using `FBO`s (OpenGL frame buffer objects). You draw into one `FBO`, then switch drawing to a new FBO while you save off the previous one. You can ping-pong back-and-forth between the 2 FBOs. [Here are the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html) for using `FBO`s on iOS.

Comment: Thanks, but just out of curiosity is there a way to force the erase command to only occur *after* the mainImage.image variable is set and drawn to the screen ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about that.